# How to find and serve JavaScript files with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to install "[wysiwyg-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/wysiwyg-rails)" and "[toastr-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/toastr-rails)".

And I also tried to install alternative gems like "[Summernote](https://summernote.org)" to avoid the error, but the same error happens "Module not found". The CSS files are loaded successful, but the JavaScript file doesn't load.

Installing the Summernote gem using:

application.js:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("summernote/summernote-bs4.min")
```

aplication.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "summernote-bs4";
```

Everything is configured and when I try to load the page the Chrome console shows:

```
application.js:9 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'summernote/summernote-bs4.min'

Application.js line 9: `require("summernote/summernote-bs4.min")`
```

And the server terminal displays the message:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'summernote/summernote-bs4.min' in '/d/myproject/app/javascript/packs'
```

I'm using Ruby 2.7.0p0 and Rails 6.0.2.1 and I have jQuery and popper installed by yarn.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to fix the error or trying to find alternate gems and need recommendations? Please rephrase your question to make it clear.

Comment: You are right, it wasn't clear. I rephrase some part of the question. Now I think it's clear that I have tried to install alternative gems only to avoid the error. The gems are working but only if I add the js files by CDN or copying the js files to the javascript folder. Only using "require("summernote/summernote-bs4.min")" it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, gems are meant to be used with Sprockets (the assets pipeline). Gems that support Webpacker integration usually have a matching [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/package/@rails/ujs)/[npm](https://yarnpkg.com/package/turbolinks) package.

I haven't even found a way to make a gem with JavaScript assets that are automatically recognized by the Webpacker compiler. You have to add a JavaScript package *or* copy the needed JavaScript into the JavaScripts folder.

When using Webpacker, it's easier to add third-party code using npm/yarn packages instead of Rails gems if you need assets.

Comment: I didn't know it. I thought after add gem line, css lines and js lines (require("summernote/summernote-bs4.min")) everything works well. Now I know that I have to add a js package or copy the needed js into the javascripts folder. Thank you!!

Comment: That process of adding a gem and css and js require worked for the Sprockets' assets pipeline. If you use webpacker it doesn't work out of the box because webpacker can't find the js inside the gem's assets folder.